# ¿Cómo puedo pintar un spinner en plant uml?

Tags: spinner, plantuml, wireframe

Estoy tratando de hacer un wireframe mediante el tipo de diagrama salt de plantuml, pero noté que no tiene el componente spinner por defecto.

De que manera podría lograr ese efecto?

### Mi código de inicio

```
@startuml
salt
{
  {^"Compra"
    Número de boletos: |"5"
  }
 
  Total: $0.00
  [Pagar]


}
@enduml
```

[image: Visual con campo de texto en vez de spinner]

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que he logrado y se ve bastante consistente:

```
@startuml
salt
{
  {^"Compra"
    Número de boletos:| {+5|<&caret-top>
    .|<&caret-bottom>}
  }

  Total: $0.00
  [Pagar]


}
@enduml
```

[image: intento de spinner]

Basicamente uso los corchetes para poner los dos renglones con sus iconos de flecha hacia arriba y flecha hacia abajo